# Is there definitive information about how long dropped items stay around for a way of permanent storage?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am somewhat running out of storage space, as I am unsure about what to do with a lot of items (keep, sell, dismantle etc.), so I was looking for a way to permanently store them somewhere. Now there are no chests or houses for your storage like in other games, and looking around people suggest to just find a nice spot and dump stuff there, while others say that is a bad idea. Current hypothesis about how long it stays there include:

- Forever
- Until the next patch making savegame files incompatible
- A certain (amounts varies) ingame time
- Until you travel far away enough
- Certain mainline quest events
- A certain amount of items are lying around in total throughout the whole world (kinda first dropped vanishes first if a list is full)
- One of the above but depending on the area

So is there any confirmed method of dumping stuff safely somewhere so I could in my lvl 1 time dump something and then come back there and collect it shortly before end game, and it is guaranteed to stay there (minus bugs, obviusly)?

<sub>Note that I am on a PS4 so PC mods or console commands are out of the question.</sub>

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a solution for your permanent storage problem: About two weeks ago, CD Projekt Red announced patch 1.07 which will add "_a player stash for storing items, available in various locations throughout the game. Stash locations are marked on the player's map._" See [this forum post](http://forums.cdprojektred.com/threads/52056-Patch-1-07-coming-soon-to-all-platforms!).

Comment: @Exa: oh that is a nice thing to hear, and since it is a solution to my problem, it might qualify as an officially confirmed method of dumping stuff somewhere, if nothing else pops up... ^^ when will we get this patch for PS4? I might stop playing until then ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not a solution to your original question, but a solution for your permanent storage problem: About two weeks ago, CD Projekt Red announced patch 1.07 which will add a permanent storage.

> A player stash for storing items, available in various locations
>   throughout the game. Stash locations are marked on the player's map.

See [this forum post](http://forums.cdprojektred.com/threads/52056-Patch-1-07-coming-soon-to-all-platforms!) and the [official change log](http://forums.cdprojektred.com/threads/52492-Patch-1-07-Changelog).

CD Projekt Red didn't give any details about the release date of the patch. They only stated that the PC version is ready and the console versions are waiting for certification.

Comment: Also in 1.07: all alchemy and crafting items will become 0 weight, saving A lot of weight

Comment: At the weekend I installed 1.07 for my PS4 and indeed you have stashes, but you can not store all kinds of items there. A lot of items have indeed now 0 weight (I wish they had made this an option in difficulty settings but well) so storing them is not needed. But unless I am mistaken, a few items still cannot be stored in the stashes. But this seems to be as safe as you can get at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally, I dropped some crossbow bolts by the blacksmith in Heiriarch's square in Novigrad 10 something hours in. When I went back to get his Wolf gear maps 90 something hours later they were still there. That was PC though.

So on PC they appear to stay (effectively) infinitely.

Comment: This should possibly be a comment on the original question, @Dallium.

Comment: @Jeeva Why? It answers the question.

Comment: My personal view is that "Anecdotally" doesn't cover "Definitive information about", and so it _doesn't_ answer the question. Apologies if that seems harsh. @QPaysTaxes

Comment: @Jeeva Ah, that seems fair. We have differing opinions then, it seems. Might make a good meta question, though! (Unless there already is one. I'm new here. I wouldn't know)

Comment: @Jeeva Anecdotal answers obviously carry less weight than those based on official or reliable sources but are acceptable if the latter can't be found, as seems to be the case here. This varies from site to site but anecdotal answers are more common on Arqade given its subject matter. If we wanted to argue the semantics Dallium would just have to add "No, but" to his answer.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: anecdotally, I once had my arm in some 27kV power supply with a nice arc going through and around it.So 27kV appears to be safe for humans to touch. I specifically asked this question because there are tons of anecdotal answers to it out there, and I summarized what all I found say, so I am clearly searching for a definitive way of telling whether it is safe, not for yet another one of those I already found tons of that contradict each other.

Comment: @All and all we have in this case in anecdotes. Some users report their stuff despawns, some users report their stuff stays forever. The very fact that we have differing experiences implies that there isn't a definitive answer. Or if there is, it's something to the effect of "On [x] version of the game, if you leave stuff [in a specific place], it'll stay there, otherwise all bets are off"

Comment: @PlasmaHH Fair enough. However, I wasn't saying its a good answer, or what you're looking for. I said IMO it's not a non-answer.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: In that sense, it is an answer to another question. "Can you tell me when the next bus arrives?" "oh, the bus, see when I was younger once the bus..."